# Change route group prefix when changed locale

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization

I want to change route group prefixes when changed locale.

For example, if the locale is en:

```
     Route::group(['prefix' => 'giveaway'], function () {

     });
```

if the locale is tr:

```
     Route::group(['prefix' => 'cekilis'], function () {

     });
```

How should i make this.

I tried

```
   'prefix'=>__('routes.prefix')
```

But app can't access current locale in routes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use middleware to set the locale as dynamic

create a middleware just like below:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Language
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        \App::setLocale($request->locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And registe this middleware in app\Http\Kernel:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
            // ...
            \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
            // ...
    ]
];
```

finally you can call your middleware on you route file

```
Route::middleware('language')->group(function ($locale) {

    //You have a condition as you wish

    if ($locale == 'en') {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'giveaway'], function () {
        .......

        });
    } elseif ($locale == 'tr') {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'cekilis'], function () {
        ........

        });
    }

});
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. I try this, but doesn't work.

I write some route in the groups like;

` 
Route::get('/', function ($locale) {
                return 'asd';
            })->name("d.test");
`
but the error is "Route [d.test] not defined"